# Lucene 4.x - How to get results for query

Tags: java, lucene

I have problem with getting result docs from my boolean query.

Here is my indexing that should be working.

```
    this.analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
    this.index = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, this.analyzer);
    IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(this.index, config);
    for(myDocClass d : docs){
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new StringField("title", d.getTitle(), Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("description", d.getDescription(), Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new StringField("pubDate", DateTools.dateToString(d.getPubDate(), DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE), Field.Store.YES));
        w.addDocument(doc);
    w.close()
```

And here is my test search.

```
    IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(this.index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();

    bq.add( new TermQuery(new Term("title", "beaver")) , BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)  ;

    TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(bq,10);

    System.out.println(searcher.doc(50).getField("title").stringValue());
    System.out.println(bq.toString());
    System.out.println(topDocs.totalHits);
```

result print is:

Is Canada a beaver or a bear?
title:beaver
0

So it claims there is no doc with title including "beaver" but there is.

Comment: have you closed your writer or committed the data?

Comment: Your code is just fine for me, make sure that the document has a `beaver` value for title.

Comment: For some reason it works after I changed the title's StringField -> TextField. thx anyway!

Comment: @osguosgu - By way of explanation: `StringField` is unanalyzed, it indexes the entire field as a single token, and so will only find matches on the *entire field*.  It should be used for atomic strings, like id numbers and such.  `TextField` is appropriate for textual content that should be analyzed and tokenized for effective searching.